# An author/book that described the future history of humanity, going as far as the Big Crunch?

Tags: story-identification

Read him on the internet some years ago, and lost all reference.

He glossed over the future history of humanity, going fully to the Big Crunch. At one point there was a glacial age, and people had some kind of talking cows that were "milked" for meat. Then humanity was somehow hibernating, and a population of some kind of homunculi lived within the hibernating bodies with a lifespan of 24 hours, and an adventurous homunculus starts an odissey through the body. At some other point people were shepherding stars to defend themselves against a collapsing universe.

I think the author was British.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you're referring to *Vacuum Diagrams*, a collection of Stephen Baxter's short fiction covering a few million years in his Xeelee universe.  There are three stories in the setting with the humans and the cow-trees: "The Shell", "The Eighth Room", and "The Baryonic Lords."

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82808/what-science-fiction-saga-has-species-at-war-over-different-kinds-of-stars for more on Xeelee